# Change Date format in List view in WinForm ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a WinForm ListView which i am populating as follows:

```
lvVchList.Items.Clear();
while (rdrLV.Read())
{
    String dt = rdrLV["v_ctra_date"].ToString();
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt));
    lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
    lvi.SubItems.Add(rdrLV["v_ctra_no"].ToString());//
    lvi.SubItems.Add(rdrLV["v_ctra_id"].ToString());//
    lvVchList.Items.Add(lvi);
    i++;
}
```

All the data are loading fine but the in the first column, the date is showing as

```
21/02/2015 00:00:00
```

I want it show as

```
21/02/2015
```

the date formatting is not working. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `dt` in this case is not `DateTime` it is a string, so `MM/dd/yyyy` format will not be applied on a string.

Comment: what is the type for `rdrLV["v_ctra_date"].`?  is it `DateTime` ?

Comment: yes its Date field

Comment: Modify and use this line `ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", rdrLV["v_ctra_date"]));`, also note, you mentioned in question you want it in `dd/MM/yyyy` format but you are using `MM//dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: Thanks Hari, i understood what you were trying to point to....I have corrected my code and now its working fine..

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it fixed your problem.